# Android-приложение на tesseract работает для Android 7.0 и крашится на 5.1 и ниже без выдачи ошибок

Tags: java, android, android-studio, распознавание-символов

Я создал простое приложение с использованием библиотеки tesseract:

Файл манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.skolos.sum">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Код главной активности:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;
private TessBaseAPI mTess;
Bitmap imageBitmap;
Bitmap image;
String datapath = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Context context = MainActivity.this;


    //init image
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),      R.drawable.test_image);

    //initialize Tesseract API
    String language = "eng";
    datapath = context.getFilesDir()+ "/tesseract/";
    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();

    checkFile(new File(datapath + "tessdata/"));

    mTess.init(datapath, language);

}

public boolean init(String datapath, String language) {
    if (datapath == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must not be null!");
    }
    if (!datapath.endsWith(File.separator)) {
        datapath += File.separator;
    }
    File tessdata = new File(datapath + "tessdata");
    if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");
    }
    return init(datapath, language);
}

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

public void getImage(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        String OCRresult = null;
        mTess.setImage(imageBitmap);
        OCRresult = mTess.getUTF8Text();
        EditText OCRTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OCRTextView);
        OCRTextView.setText(OCRresult);


    }
}

private void checkFile(File dir) {
    if (!dir.exists() && dir.mkdirs()) {
        copyFiles();
    }
    if (dir.exists()) {
        String datafilepath = datapath + "/tessdata/eng.traineddata";
        File datafile = new File(datafilepath);

        if (!datafile.exists()) {
            copyFiles();
        }
    }
}

private void copyFiles() {
    try {
        String filepath = datapath + "/tessdata/eng.traineddata";
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream instream = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
        OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = instream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outstream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }


        outstream.flush();
        outstream.close();
        instream.close();

        File file = new File(filepath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Код работает в эмуляторе с API 24:

[image: Android 7.0 - работает]

Не работает с API 22 и ниже:

[image: Android 5.1 - крашится без ошибок в консоли]

У меня есть предположение, что косяк может быть в этом куске кода в главной активности:

```
    //initialize Tesseract API
    String language = "eng";
    datapath = context.getFilesDir()+ "/tesseract/";
    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();

    checkFile(new File(datapath + "tessdata/"));

    mTess.init(datapath, language);
```

Очевидно, крашится на инициализации, видимо, библиотека не может открыть файл языка по адресу datapath.
Внимание, знатоки! Вопрос:
В чем может быть отличие в разных версиях Android и как заставить это работать и в старых версиях прошивки?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в файл манифеста `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>`, тогда при работе с *API 22* ошибка должна исчезнуть.

Comment: нет. Результат тот же. Крашится без выдачи ошибок в консоль, с API 24 работает(

Comment: @larrymacbarry, тогда добавьте, пожалуйста, логи с ошибкой в сообщение

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.skolos.sum, PID: 2794 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.skolos.sum/com.example.skolos.sum.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data file not found at /data/data/com.example.skolos.sum/files/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

В одном из запусков выдало, что не находит файл с языком. Почти всер другие разы приложение падает без ошибок в логе вобще